# How can I detect when an inactive button is clicked in JQM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I don't quite understand how JQM works with [radio buttons](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/forms/). I have the following code:

```
<fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-2a"> Brands </label>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" type="radio" checked="checked" class="active" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-2b"> Stores </label>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" type="radio" class=""  autocomplete="off">
</fieldset>
```

JQM does its magic and adds HTML / classes. The result is this:

```
<fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all"><div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">                
    <div class="ui-radio">
      <label for="radio-choice-h-2a" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-first-child ui-btn-active ui-radio-on"> Brands </label>
      <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" type="radio" checked="checked" class="active" autocomplete="off" data-cacheval="false">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-radio">
      <label for="radio-choice-h-2b" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-last-child ui-radio-off"> Stores </label>
      <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" type="radio" class="" autocomplete="off" data-cacheval="true"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I can add logic when a button changes state:

```
$(document).on('change', '#main-search-result .ui-radio', function(){
  //Do something
});
```

**Q1:** Why is this working? `.ui-radio` is just a DIV and does not have a state like a radiobutton.

**Q2:** How can I detect when the **unchecked** button is clicked?

UPDATE

I've discovered [checkboxradio](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/) in the API:

```
var disabled = $( "#main-search-result .ui-radio" ).checkboxradio( "option", "disabled" );
```

But I'm not sure if I'm using the right selector.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled is not the same thing as unchecked. Disabled is when you want to prevent the user from changing the state of the button (button is grayed out).

jQM uses the label element as the actual button the user clicks. Checked items have the class `ui-btn-active`, while unchecked items don't have this class.  So you could detect clicks on unselected items like this:

```
$(document).on("click", '.ui-radio label:not(.ui-btn-active)', function(e){
    alert("unchecked button clicked!");
});
```

`.ui-radio label:not(.ui-btn-active)` means all labels that do not have the `ui-btn-active` class, that are within containers having the `ui-radio` class.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/th2yya12/)**

Demo includes just detecting the change on the underlying radio inputs.